Probability Density Function with Ramachandran function of MDAnalysis in Python
My data consists with a trajectory of a MD we've done with a protein. My idea is to plot a Ramachandran graph with a color gradient. The has the information of all the frames in the trajectory, but with the same color and size, because of it, it's very hard to read the image.
I'm using the following code to get the Ramachandran data.
import MDAnalysis as mda

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from MDAnalysis.analysis.dihedrals import Ramachandran

u = mda.Universe(topology, trajectory)
r = u.select_atoms("protein")

R = Ramachandran(r).run()

Then, to plot it, I'm using the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
R.plot(ax=ax, color='y', marker='.')
plt.show()

Ramachandran Image
I'm hoping to get a image like this:
The area where the values appears more frequently should have a color, while, the area where the values don't appear as much, it will have another color. So it's like a "3d probabily density function".
Maybe I'm going for something way out of my league. But, for now, it's the path I can see to get where I want. If someone has a tip for me going foward, I will appreciate it!

The MDAnalysis Userguide: Ramachandran analysis is a good starting point with the reference density plotted in the background
R.plot(color='black', marker='.', alpha=0.2, ref=True)


I assume you want to do something like the reference density that was added in blue in the background.
The basic idea is to use numpy.histogrammdd on all the angles to create a density and then plot the density with matplotlib's contourf:
Import modules
import MDAnalysis as mda
from MDAnalysis.analysis.dihedrals import Ramachandran

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Example data
I am using an example trajectory but you should use your own data:
from MDAnalysisTests import datafiles as data
u = mda.Universe(data.PSF, data.DCD)

Ramachandran analysis
Let's select the protein and run the Ramachandran analysis (as you already did)
protein = u.select_atoms("protein")
R = Ramachandran(protein).run(verbose=True)

Angle data and histogramming
The angles are stored in R.results.angles as an array of shape (N_frames, N_residues, 2) for phi and psi. We reshape it into a list of pairs (phi, psi) as our data, i.e., we are histogramming over all residues and trajectory frames:
phi_psi = R.results.angles.reshape(-1, 2)

We now set up the bins for the 2D-histogram (angle_bins, change num=90 to another number if you have more data and want finer resolution), calculate the midpoints of the bins (angle_midpoints) for plotting, and calculate the density with np.histogramdd:
angle_bins = np.linspace(-180, 180, num=90, endpoint=True)
angle_midpoints = 0.5 * (angle_bins[:-1] + angle_bins[1:])
density, edges = np.histogramdd(phi_psi, bins=[angle_bins, angle_bins], density=True)

Density plotting
With the density data we can use any of matplotlib's 2D plotting functions; you could use imshow or contour but here we use matplotlib.pyplot.contourf for filled contours:
# create the proper coordinates to plot on
PHI, PSI = np.meshgrid(angle_midpoints, angle_midpoints)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)

# contour plot with the "hot" colormap
cs = ax.contourf(PHI, PSI, density.T, cmap=plt.matplotlib.colormaps['hot'])
cbar = fig.colorbar(cs)

# label the axes and put a degree symbol on each tick label
ax.set(xticks=range(-180, 181, 60), yticks=range(-180, 181, 60), xlabel=r"$\phi$", ylabel=r"$\psi$")
degree_formatter = plt.matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(r"%g$^\circ$")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(degree_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(degree_formatter)

Note that we need to use the transpose of the density, density.T for phi and psi to line up correctly (I only realized that after I compared the density to the scatterplot from R.plot()).
The result is the image below.

One issue with the density is that only the high density region is clearly visible.
To at least make clearer that there's data in other regions, too, we can plot a pseudo-free energy landscape by taking the negative logarithm of the density and plotting with the reversed color scale
cs = ax.contourf(PHI, PSI, -np.log(density.T), cmap=plt.matplotlib.colormaps['hot_r'])


and that shows clearer the regions with lower probability density and higher pseudo-free energy:

